# Identifying the position in the original string from a given Boost token_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, stl, tokenize

If a string has been processed using a Boost tokenizer is it possible to get the position in the original string that a given token iterator is pointing to:

```
boost:tokenizer<> tok( "this is the original string" );
for(tokenizer<>::iterator it=tok.begin(); it!=tok.end();++it)
{
    std::string strToken = *it;
    int charPos = it.?                /* IS THERE A METHOD? */
}
```

I realize I could create a specific char_separator with a defined list of 'kept delimiters' and specify keep_empty_tokens to try and track the progression of the iterator myself but I was hoping there was an easier way using just the iterator itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be what you're looking for:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
  typedef boost::tokenizer<> tok_t;

  std::string const s = "this is the original string";
  tok_t const tok(s);
  for (tok_t::const_iterator it = tok.begin(), it_end = tok.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
  {
    std::string::difference_type const offset = it.base() - s.begin() - it->size();
    std::cout << offset << "\t::\t" << *it << '\n';
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc2c103d930fc6f9)</kbd>

Comment: Is there any way to find the start of the tok if we modify the original string within the while loop (like may be erase one character based on some condition)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the end of current token, `base()` member function
might meet the purpose:

```
std::string s = "this is the original string";
boost::tokenizer<> tok(s);
for(boost::tokenizer<>::iterator it=tok.begin(); it!=tok.end();++it)
{
    int charPos = it.base() - s.begin();
}
```

Unfortunately, there seems not to be the way to retrieve the beginning
of current token in `boost::tokenizer`.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the other answer just because it was more complete.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 int charPos = it - tok.begin() ;
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it? It was the first thing I tried but it doesn't work, the compiler fails with distance_to not accessible (wrong type of iterator).

Comment: According to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm the iterator is of type std::string::const_iterator, which should just be a const pointer unless you're running some fancy debug implementation of STL.